# How to rename build output file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I just made some c++ application, using NotificationIcon sample from Microsoft as a reference, and thus I'm stuck with the NotificationIcon.exe output file. The name is really lame and I'd like to change it. I've tried renaming the exe, renaming the solution, the project - whatever else - and my programm just exited with code 0x00 after building. What else should I try?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing, but there were a few steps I had to follow in VS2019 just to get set up.  If you are not in a similar state, the rest of the answer might not apply.

1. Downloading the sample: I had to install the Windows 7 SDK, as the download page didn't seem to exist anymore.  I'm not sure if you found it elsewhere, in which case you might be starting from different sources.
2. Converting the .vcproj file to .vcxproj.  Visual Studio no longer supports .vcproj, and opening the solution triggered this conversion automatically.

Now, once I have a .vcxproj file, there are two routes to setting the name of the exe:

1. Right-click the project in VS, click Properties, and find the Target Name field.  This defaults to `$(ProjectName)` so I would have expected that renaming the .vcxproj would have renamed the .exe file.
2. Edit the .vcxproj file directly, adding `<TargetName>Foo</TargetName>` into the section that starts with `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">`